# How to fire up all docker containers on a same local ip address in django?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, ip

I am writing a django based application with docker where there are 3 projects apps running in different containers. All django applications run at `0.0.0.0:8000`.

But when I check the ip address of containers to browser the application in browser, they all run at different ip addresses:

project1 runs at `172.18.0.10:8000` can be accessed at: `172.18.0.10:8000/app1`
project2 runs at `172.18.0.9:8000` can be accessed at: `172.18.0.9:8000/app2`
project3 runs at `172.18.0.7:8000` can be accessed at: `172.18.0.7:8000/app3`

which makes the hyperlinks of my app unusable. How do I run all the containers at one single ip, 'localhost:8000'?

Any suggestions where I am going wrong?

Comment: You have to use a single container. You can't use one ip while using 3 different container

Comment: You have to `docker run -p` a different port for each container; you can't run three different services on the same port, Docker or otherwise.  The Docker-internal IP addresses aren't useful (they change whenever you restart a container and aren't visible from other hosts); don't bother looking them up.

Comment: Is there anyway i can map my localhost to all of the 3 ips. Then I can use just my localhost in browser?

Comment: Why don't you use [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to unify all those apps/containers and assign each of them different ports?
You can port-forward those ports in localhost.

Comment: because changing ports in docker-compose will screw up my CI/CD in actual server.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in the design, mapping multiple containers to one ip+port is simply impossible. One port on one ip is always one application that listens, no matter if it is container application or not.

Simple prove: And who would then decide to which container to send the request? To all of them? Then who would decide which response is the correct one? That's what are ip addresses and ports for, to be able to send request to specific aplications on specific machines.

I think you should reconsider whatever you are doing, and do a bit more research on networking. There are several online courses on that. (I don't want to discourage you in any way, just aim you the right direction)

Simple solution without redesign you app, is putting in front of your app reverse proxy (e. g. nginx). That's the response to my rhetorical question. Reverse proxy can be a middle man that can decide to which application send the request based on something else then ip/port. Reverse proxy listens on some specific port and then by rules you provide to it (e. g. path based), can proxy the request to specific app/ip/port and proxy the response back.

But reverse proxy in this case is more a hack than proper solution, keep that in mind.